# Why does a cnn with keras not learn?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am kind of new to deep learning and especially keras, and I have an assignment from university to train a CNN and learn about it, using keras. I am using the MURA dataset (skeletonal radiography).

What I have done until now is to go over all images from the dataset and split the training set into train and validation (90/10).

I am using a CNN that has been given in the paper and I am not allowed to modify it until the second task. The first task is to observe and understand the CNN.

```
def run():
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train_data',
                                                        target_size=(227,227),
                                                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        color_mode='grayscale'
                                                        )


    val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_data',
                                                        target_size=(227,227),
                                                        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                        class_mode='binary',
                                                        color_mode='grayscale'
                                                        )

    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(7,7),strides=2, input_shape=(227,227,1)))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(128, (5,5), strides=2 ))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=1))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(384, (3,3), strides=1))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=1))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), strides=1))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))
    classifier.add(Flatten())
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=2048))
    classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1))
    classifier.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    classifier.summary()

    # from keras.optimizers import SGD

    # sg = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

    classifier.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(),loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    classifier.fit_generator(train_generator,
                            steps_per_epoch= training_len//BATCH_SIZE,
                            epochs=10,
                            validation_data=val_generator,
                            validation_steps= valid_len//BATCH_SIZE,
                            shuffle=True,
                            verbose=1)
    classifier.save_weights('first_model_weights.h5')
    classifier.save('first_model.h5')
```

The problem I am having is that if I run this, it just does not learn. Or at least I think it doesn't.
The output looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/10
575/575 [==============================] - 693s 1s/step - loss: 0.6767 - acc: 0.5958 - val_loss: 0.6751 - val_acc: 0.5966
Epoch 2/10
575/575 [==============================] - 207s 359ms/step - loss: 0.6760 - acc: 0.5948 - val_loss: 0.6752 - val_acc: 0.5958
Epoch 3/10
575/575 [==============================] - 258s 448ms/step - loss: 0.6745 - acc: 0.5983 - val_loss: 0.6748 - val_acc: 0.5958
Epoch 4/10
575/575 [==============================] - 165s 287ms/step - loss: 0.6760 - acc: 0.5950 - val_loss: 0.6757 - val_acc: 0.5947
Epoch 5/10
575/575 [==============================] - 166s 288ms/step - loss: 0.6761 - acc: 0.5948 - val_loss: 0.6731 - val_acc: 0.6016
Epoch 6/10
575/575 [==============================] - 167s 290ms/step - loss: 0.6742 - acc: 0.5990 - val_loss: 0.6778 - val_acc: 0.5875
Epoch 7/10
575/575 [==============================] - 206s 359ms/step - loss: 0.6762 - acc: 0.5938 - val_loss: 0.6721 - val_acc: 0.6038
Epoch 8/10
575/575 [==============================] - 165s 286ms/step - loss: 0.6762 - acc: 0.5938 - val_loss: 0.6763 - val_acc: 0.5947
Epoch 9/10
575/575 [==============================] - 164s 286ms/step - loss: 0.6751 - acc: 0.5972 - val_loss: 0.6787 - val_acc: 0.5897
Epoch 10/10
575/575 [==============================] - 168s 292ms/step - loss: 0.6750 - acc: 0.5971 - val_loss: 0.6722 - val_acc: 0.6022
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code? Is it the dataset splitting? I am currently in a dark spot and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried removing the Dropout layers? I think the performance of the original model is also important to see what is going on here. At least the training accuracy will increase and we will see what happen with the validation accuracy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said, I am supposed to train it using this net. I managed to do it simply by not using an ImageDataGenerator and just reading each image, resizing, reshaping and then store them into a numpy array.